# Append Method Linked List... It keeps deleting the last input

Tags: java, linked-list

```
public void append(int data) {
    Node newNode = new Node(data);

    if (head == null) {
        head = new Node(data);
        return;
    } else { 
        Node last = head;
        while(last.nextNode != null) {
            last = last.nextNode;
        }
        last.nextNode = newNode;
    }
    return;
}


public void printList(){
    Node temp = head;
    while (temp != null && temp.nextNode != null){
        System.out.print(temp.data + " " );
        temp = temp.nextNode;
    }
    temp = temp.nextNode;
}
```

Input: 4,5,6,9,9
Output: 4,5,6,9

This is the output I get it keeps deleting the last input.....
Changes made

Comment: On a side note, those `return` statements are useless.

Comment: when i append integers like lets say (4,5,6,9,9,10)... all the integers show except 10

Comment: Yes, I pointed out something else. Also, I do not believe your error is in the piece of code you have shown us. Must be somewhere else in your code, if you can, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60253048/edit) and add it here.

Comment: show how you print output

Comment: How do you print the results?

Comment: It should be `temp.nextNode` and not `temp.NextNode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to print last node. You check not only if `temp` is not null, but also if it has next node after it - therefore you exit while loop before last node was actually printed.

Either change conditions or print last node right after while loop (I would suggest first option).

First option:

```
public void printList() {
    Node temp = head;
    while (temp != null) {
      System.out.print(temp.data + " ");
      temp = temp.nextNode;
    }
}
```

Second option:

```
public void printList(){
    Node temp = head;
    while (temp != null && temp.nextNode != null){
        System.out.print(temp.data + " " );
        temp = temp.nextNode;
    }
    // print last node here
    System.out.print(temp.data);
    temp = temp.nextNode; 
}
```